# How to add onTap() or onPressed() to ExpansionTileCard in flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter

I am using below ExpansionTileCard widget for the ListView.Builder, I am able to generate the list using this, but I am not able add the functionality if the user presses the item in the list and then to perform a FlutterToast Action, I tried to find the solution with the flutter package but no success yet

Please guide me how to do that.

```
  child:  ExpansionTileCard(

    leading: CircleAvatar(child: Image.network(widget.Picurl)),
    title: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("text1"),
        Text('text2'),
      ],
    ),
    subtitle: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Text1"),
            SizedBox(width: 5,),
            Text("Text2")
          ],
        ),

      ],
    ),
    children: <Widget>[
      Divider(
        thickness: 1.0,
        height: 1.0,

      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 16.0,
            vertical: 8.0,
          ),
          child: Text(
          widget.postcontent,
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .body1
                .copyWith(fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ButtonBar(
        alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        buttonHeight: 52.0,
        buttonMinWidth: 90.0,
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
            onPressed: () {


               },
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.star),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                ),
                Text('Button1'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
            onPressed: () {



            },
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.open_in_browser),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                ),
                Text('Button2'),

              ],
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the widget you want to register tap or pressed gestures inside a `GestureDetector`widget and select the appropriate callback for needed gesture events

```dart
GestureDetector(
   onTap: () {
       // your code here
   },
   child: ExpansionTileCard(
       ........
   ),
),
```

For more details and gesture options : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping with a GestureDetector.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ripple effect when the widget is being tapped , you should wrap the widget inside `InkWell`

Here is how -

```
 InkWell(
   onTap: () {
       // your code here
   },
   child: ExpansionTileCard(
       ........
   ),
),
```